# appium session is not captured in appium desktop

Tags: selenium, appium

I am trying to capture the element of my application. But appium desktop neither does load nor does it throw an error. please [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4hvv.png)

App has launched successfully

these are my desired capabilities:

```
{
  "platformVersion": "8.0.0",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "deviceName": "pixcel 2 xl",
  "appActivity": "com.americanexpress.merchantmobileapp.development.MainActivity",
  "appPackage": "com.americanexpress.android.merchantmobileapp.au.development",
  "no-reset": "true",
  "full-reset": "false"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your logs as well!!

Comment: please find the log below: